# If I populate lots with various households, will the sims find careers and work on their own?

Tags: the-sims-4

For the households that aren't being played, how much autonomy do the sims that live in lots have? Will they find careers on their own? If I place them into a career, will they progress based on the needs of their career and/or their interest/personality? Will they make friends (and even get married or have kids)?

Similar questions for the generated townies that don't live in lots. How much autonomy do they have to find and grow in careers and interact with households that I'm not playing?

Answer (score 3):

I've seen both regular and townie sims interact with each other in public areas - therefore making friends, but I've found they also improve (and maintain) that relationship aswell.

I've had two generated sims move in, have children, and start off in a career without me access the household. (I would assume that all sims improve in all careers despite traits and skills too.)

An active sim (i.e. Summer Holiday) would jog and build fitness skill. It's the same with other emotional traits too.

Skills and their preferred Traits:

- Comedy and Mischief - Goofball
- Fitness - Active
- Charisma - Self-Assured
- Painting, Violin, Piano, Guitar, Cooking, Gourmet Cooking, Mixology - Creative, Gloomy
- Logic, Handiness, Rocket Science, Gardening - Genius

If (NPC) sims have access to skill building items (i.e. chessboard) they will use it and build skill.

Basically, unattended sims- both regular and generated are the same (autonomy wise).